# What is wrong with this code (German)

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JavaScript so I decided to learn the basics and wanted to launch this Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <title> JavaScript  </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascrip">
        var global = 5;
        function one(){
            var lokal = 4;
            document.write(global);
            document.write(lokal);
        };
        function two(){
            document.write(global);
        };
        one();
        two();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the browser does Nothing! Where is the error?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascrip">`  should be `<script type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt write this line correctly. There's a spelling mistake its javascript not 'javascrip'.

Replace

```
<script type="text/javascrip">
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Typo:
`<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script type="text/javascrip">`